# Is it possible for a Perl subroutine to force its caller to return?

Tags: perl

If I have Perl module like

```
 package X;
```

and an object like

```
 my $x = X->new ();
```

Inside *X.pm*, I write an error handler for `$x` called `handle_error`, and I call it

```
 sub check_size
 {
     if ($x->{size} > 1000) {
         $x->handle_error ();
         return;
     }
 }
```

Is there any way to make `handle_error` force the return from its caller routine? In other words, in this example, can I make `handle_error` do `return` in `check_size` without actually writing `return` there?

Comment: I'm going to get all OOP naggy and bug you about violating encapsultion by accessing `size` directly.  IME, it's a good idea to always access attributes through method calls.  Even inside a class it makes the class more heritable and improves the ability to redesign the underlying attributes without breaking compatibility.  It is future proofing.

Answer (score 11):

The only reasonable way to backtrack multiple levels up the call stack is by throwing an exception/dying.

That said, you *really* should reconsider what you want to do.  A programmer (including yourself, six months from now) will expect that, when a function call completes, the statement after it will execute (unless an exception is thrown).  Violating that expectation will cause bugs which are caused in `handle_error`, but appear to be with the code which called `handle_error`, making them extremely difficult to debug.  This is Not A Good Thing.

You're also making the assumption that there is *absolutely no situation* in which continuing after an error is handled will be appropriate.  Hardcoding an assumption like that is practically a sure guarantee that, as soon as you've had time to forget it, you'll come across a case where you need to continue after calling `handle_error` (and then waste huge amounts of time trying to figure out why the code after `handle_error` doesn't get run).

And then there's the assumption that you'll *always* want to skip back *exactly* two levels in the call stack.  That's another assumption that will fail as soon as it's hardcoded.  Not only will there be cases where the calling code should continue, there will also be cases where you need to go three levels up the call stack.

So just have `handle_error` exit by calling `die` instead of `return` and trap the exception at the appropriate level where execution should continue.  You don't know every place where the sub will ever be called, so you can't predict how many levels back it will need to go.

In the code at hand, if the extra line to just say `return` is bothering you, you can use `return $x->handle_error;`  You can even get rid of the enclosing scope and make it `return $x->handle_error if $x->{size} > 1000;`  There - three lines removed rather than just one, plus a pair of braces and two pairs of parentheses as a free bonus.

Finally, I would also suggest changing the name of `handle_error` to better reflect what it actually does.  (`report_error`, maybe?)  "Handling an error" usually means cleaning things up to resolve the error so that execution to continue.  If you want your `handle_error` to prevent the code which called it from continuing, then it seems very unlikely that it's cleaning things up to make continuation possible and, once again, it will cause nasty, hard-to-debug surprises for future programmers using this code.

Comment: I would like to know if there is any way to do this, even an unreasonable way.

Comment: @Kinopiko, you might be able to do it with some crazy XS code.  But IMO, this design sounds like walking barefoot over broken glass to get to a gun so that you can shoot yourself in the foot.  But what the heck? They're your feet.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [goto &NAME](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/goto.html), your return from the error handler will return to the point where `check_size` was called.

sub check_size {
    my $x = shift;  # you don't say where the $x comes fro in X.pm.
                    # I assume it is the invocant.

```
if( $x->{size} > 1000 ) {
    my $sub = $x->can('handle_error');
    goto $sub;
}
```

}

This works because `goto &NAME` transfers control to the called function without creating a new stack frame.

I use `can` to get a reference to the `handle_error` for `$x`, so that the method will work  properly with subclasses that override `handle_error`.

This design seems like a bad idea to me, though.

Perhaps this is a good place to use exceptions:

```
use Try::Tiny;
my $x = X->new();

try   {  $x->check_size }
catch {  $x->handle_error };
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I want to force this inside `handle_error` rather than in the caller. Is there any way to do that? Maybe not?

Answer (score 2):

The answer to your question is extremely difficult, and I'm not even going to field it because its a poor solution to your real problem.  What's the real problem?  The problem is that you want an error inside a deeply nested subroutine call to bubble up the stack.  This is what exceptions are for.

Here's your code rewritten to throw an exception using `croak`.

```
package X;

sub new {
    my $class = shift;
    my %args = @_;
    my $obj = bless \%args, $class;

    $obj->check_size;

    return $obj;
}

my $Max_Size = 1000;
sub check_size
{
    my $self = shift;

    if ($self->{size} > $Max_Size) {
        croak "size $self->{size} is too large, a maximum of $Max_Size is allowed";
   }
}
```

Then when the user creates an invalid object...

```
my $obj = X->new( size => 1234 );
```

`check_size` dies and throws its exception up the stack.  If the user
does nothing to stop it, they get an error message `"size 1234 is too
large, a maximum of 1000 is allowed at somefile line 234"`.  `croak`
makes sure the error message happens at the point where `new` is
called, where the user made the error, not somewhere deep inside X.pm.

Or they can write the new() in an `eval BLOCK` to trap the error.

```
my $obj = eval { X->new( size => 1234 ) } or do {
    ...something if the object isn't created...
};
```

If you want to do something more when an error occurs, you can wrap
`croak` in a method call.

```
sub error {
    my $self = shift;
    my $error = shift;

    # Leaving log_error unwritten.
    $self->log_error($error);
    croak $error;
}

my $Max_Size = 1000;
sub check_size
{
    my $self = shift;

    if ($self->{size} > $Max_Size) {
        $self->error("size $self->{size} is too large, a maximum of $Max_Size is allowed");
   }
}
```

The exception from `croak` will bubble up the stack through `error`, `check_size` and `new`.

As daotoad points out, Try::Tiny is a better exception handler than a straight `eval BLOCK`.

See [Should a Perl constructor return an undef or a "invalid" object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1498042/should-a-perl-constructor-return-an-undef-or-a-invalid-object/2860066#2860066) for more reasons why exceptions are a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Continuation::Escape](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Continuation-Escape). This would basically allow you to pass the "point-of-return" on to the error handler.

Answer (score 0):

Workaround that works but is not nice to see.

Use the select statement.

If you have a function my_func() which you call and then based on the return value you want to do some error processing and then return from the caller you could do:

```
($result = my_func()) == 0 ? return handle_error($result) : 0;
```

This is a (ugly) one-liner that substitutes:

```
$result = my_func();
if ($result == 0) {
    handle_error($result);

    return;
}
```

Convenient if you have many function to call and check return value.