# How can a Perl force its caller to return?

Tags: perl, scope, return

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible for a Perl subroutine to force its caller to return?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2871507/is-it-possible-for-a-perl-subroutine-to-force-its-caller-to-return)

I want to write a subroutine which causes the caller to return under certain conditions. This is meant to be used as a shortcut for validating input to a function. What I have so far is:

```
sub needs($$) {
    my ($condition, $message) = @_;

    if (not $condition) {
        print "$message\n";
        # would like to return from the *parent* here
    }

    return $condition;
}

sub run_find {
    my $arg = shift @_;
    needs $arg, "arg required" or return;
    needs exists $lang{$arg}, "No such language: $arg" or return;

    # etc.
}
```

The advantage of returning from the caller in `needs` would then be to avoid having to write the repetitive `or return` inside `run_find` and similar functions.

Comment: You do realize that as you've written it, `needs` will always `return $condition`, don't you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're focussing on the wrong thing here. I do this sort of thing with Data::Constraint, [Brick](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Brick), etc. and talk about this in *Mastering Perl*. With a little cleverness and thought about the structure of your program and the dynamic features that Perl has, you don't need such a regimented, procedural approach.

However, the first thing you need to figure out is what you really want to know in that calling subroutine. If you just want to know yes or no, it's pretty easy.

The problem with your `needs` is that you're thinking about calling it once for every condition, which forces you to use `needs` to control program flow. That's the wrong way to go. `needs` is only there to give you an answer. It's job is not to change program state. It becomes much less useful if you misuse it because some other calling subroutine might want to continue even if `needs` returns false. Call it once and let it return once. The calling subroutine uses the return value to decide what it should do.

The basic structure involves a table that you pass to `needs`. This is your validation profile.

```
sub run_find {
    my $arg = shift @_;
    return unless needs [
        [ sub { $arg }, "arg required" ],
        [ sub { exists $lang{$arg} }, "No such language: $arg" ],
        ];
    }
    ...
    }
```

You construct your table for whatever your requirements are. In `needs` you just process the table:

```
sub needs($$) {
    my ($table) = @_;

    foreach $test ( @$table ) {
        my( $sub, $message ) = @$test;
        unless( $sub->(...) ) {
            print $message;
            return
            }
        }

    return 1;
    }
```

Now, the really cool thing with this approach is that you don't have to know the table ahead of time. You can pull that from configuration or some other method. That also means that you can change the table dynamically. Now your code shrinks quite a bit:

```
sub run_find {
    my $arg = shift @_;
    return unless needs( $validators{run_find} );
    ...
    }
```

You cna keep going with this. In *Mastering Perl* I show a couple of solutions that completely remove that from the code and moves it into a configuration file. That is, you can change the business rules without changing the code.

Remember, almost any time that you are typing the same sequence of characters, you're probably doing it wrong. :)

Comment: +1 Gotta say that the table idea is just fantastic.

Comment: Yeah, the table idea meets my needs. It doesn't require any wacky messing with scopes, but it still cuts down on the verbosity.

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like you are re-inventing exception handling.

The `needs` function should not magically deduce its parent and interrupt the parent's control flow - that's bad manners. What if you add additional functions to the call chain, and you need to go back two or even three functions back? How can you determine this programmatically? Will the caller be expecting his or her function to return early? You should follow the principle of least surprise if you want to avoid bugs - and that means using exceptions to indicate that there is a problem, and having the caller decide how to deal with it:

```
use Carp;
use Try::Tiny;

sub run_find {
    my $arg = shift;
    defined $arg or croak "arg required";
    exists $lang{$arg} or croak "no such language: $arg"; 

    ...
}

sub parent {
    try { run_find('foo') }
    catch { print $@; }
}
```

Any code inside of the `try` block is special: if something dies, the exception is caught and stored in `$@`. In this case, the `catch` block is executed, which prints the error to STDOUT and control flow continues as normal.

Disclaimer: exception handling in Perl is a pain. I recommend [Try::Tiny](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Try::Tiny), which protects against many common gotchas (and provides familiar try/catch semantics) and [Exception::Class](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Exception::Class) to quickly make exception objects so you can distinguish between Perl's errors and your own.

For validation of arguments, you might find it easier to use a CPAN module such as [Params::Validate](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Params::Validate).

Comment: I get only error-messages if I write "catch { print $_; }" instead of "catch { print $@; }"

Comment: The problem is that the caller of `run_find` is a module outside my control (Term::Shell, if you care), and that caller doesn't wrap my call in `eval`. Since I don't want to bring down the whole process, I have to exit normally from `run_find` and handle errors some other way.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look at a similar recent question by kinopiko: 
[Is it possible for a Perl subroutine to force its caller to return?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2871507/is-it-possible-for-a-perl-subroutine-to-force-its-caller-to-return)

The executive summary for that is: best solution is to use exceptions (die/eval, Try::Tiny, etc...). You van also use GOTO and possibly Continuation::Escape

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't make sense to do things this way; ironically, ya doesn't needs `needs`.

Here's why.

- `run_find` is poorly written. If your first condition is true, you'll never test the second one since you'll have `return`ed already.
- The [`warn`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/warn.html) and [`die`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/die.html) functions will provide you printing and/or exiting behavior anyway.

Here's how I would write your `run_find` sub if you wanted to terminate execution if your argument fails (renamed it to `well_defined`):

```
sub well_defined {

    my $arg = shift;
    $arg or die "arg required";
    exists $lang{$arg} or die "no such language: $arg";
    return 1;
}
```

<strike>There should be a way to `return 0` and `warn` at the same time, but I'll need to play around with it a little more.</strike>

`run_find` can also be written to `return 0` and the appropriate `warn` message if conditions are not met, and `return 1` if they are (renamed to `well_defined`).

```
sub well_defined {

    my $arg = shift;
    $arg or warn "arg required" and return 0;
    exists $lang{$arg} or warn "no such language: $arg" and return 0;
    return 1;
}
```

This enables Boolean-esque behavior, as demonstrated below:

```
perform_calculation $arg if well_defined $arg; # executes only if well-defined
```

Comment: How about `warn "no such language", return 0;` ?

Comment: @Ether : Tried your suggestion in a Perl one-liner, it doesn't `warn` properly: `perl -e "sub rf { $arg = shift; $arg or warn qq(No arg), return 0; return 1; } print qq(Yes) if rf ;"`. Replacing the `,` with `and` does work though.

Comment: ah yes, I forgot that `warn` takes a list, so it will gobble up everything, unless we add in some parens to show where its args finish: `warn("no such language"), return 0;`