# Can I call a subroutine at a hard-coded address in Perl?

Tags: perl, eval

Let's say I have the following piece of code:

```
my $compiled = eval 'sub { print( "Hello World\n" ); }';
```

I can call this by writing:

```
$compiled->();
```

So far so good. Now imagine I create 10 functions:

```
my @fns = ();
for ( my $i = 0; $i < 10; $i++ ) {
  push( @fns, eval "sub { print( 'I am function $i\n' ); }" );
}
```

I can call these 10 functions as follows:

```
foreach ( @fns ) {
  $_->();
}
```

Now, I want to create a dynamic function that calls each of my 10 functions explicitly:

```
my $evalcode = "sub {";
foreach ( @fns ) {
    # if I print $_ it shows something like
    #   "CODE(0x94084f8)", but trying to
    #   call "CODE(0x94084f8)->()" is invalid
    $evalcode .= "$_->();";
}
$evalcode .= "}";


my $dynamic_fn = eval $evalcode;
$dynamic_fn->();
```

Is it possible to take a stringified reference to a subroutine and call this directly?

PS why, you ask? Because I would like to write a dynamic routine that constructs a chain of `if ( m/.../ ) { } elsif ( m/.../ ) { } ...` checks that then call dynamic functions depending on the input string.

Answer (score 14):

Instead of string evals, you might want to use regular lexical closures:

```
my @functions;

for my $i (0 .. 9) {
    push @functions, sub { print "I am function $i\n" };
}

my $call_all_funcs = sub {
    for my $func (@functions) {
        $func->();
    }
};

$call_all_funcs->();
```

It is also possible to retrieve a code reference based in its address, but that'd be much more elaborate, harder to understand, and generally not a very good idea.

Comment: I was going to suggest this, but I don't think it will do for the OP. I think the code of the different subs is to be generated dynamically, which is why they want to use eval.

Comment: It will. The second closure is the important bit. The list of functions generated earlier could also be generated with a string eval. But then again I still think there's ways to do whatever the OP wants without having to resort to `eval STRING` at all. Closures are really quite powerful.

Answer (score 8):

How about using a closure instead of an eval string?

```
sub combine_subrefs {
  my @subs = @_;
  return sub { foreach my $subref (@subs) { $subref->() } };
}

my $dynamic_fn = combine_subrefs( @fns );
$dynamic_fn->();
```

I'm sure you can adapt this to do the elsif thing you mentioned as well.

Answer (score 7):

re: *why, you ask? Because I would like to write a dynamic routine that constructs a chain of if ( m/.../ ) { } elsif ( m/.../ ) { } ... checks that then call dynamic functions depending on the input string.*

To create an *if & elsif* chain like you described above can be done without having to resort to [`eval`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/eval.html):

```
use 5.012;
use warnings;

my $build_ifelse_dispatch_table = sub {
    my @functions = @_;

    sub {
        my $text = shift;
        for (@functions) {
            my ($re, $code) = @$_;
            if ($text =~ $re) {
                $code->();
                last;
            }
        }
    };
};

my $dispatch_on = $build_ifelse_dispatch_table->( 
    [ qr/tom/   => sub { say "Tom!"   } ],   # if    (m/tom/)   { ... }
    [ qr/dick/  => sub { say "Dick!"  } ],   # elsif (m/dick/)  { ... }
    [ qr/harry/ => sub { say "Harry!" } ],   # elsif (m/harry/) { ... }
);


$dispatch_on->( 'peeping tom'         );  # Tom!
$dispatch_on->( 'spotty dick pudding' );  # Dick!
$dispatch_on->( 'harry potter'        );  # Harry!
$dispatch_on->( 'Tom, dick and harry' );  # Dick!
```

ref: Wikipedia entry on [Dispatch Table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dispatch_table).

/I3az/

Answer (score 4):

You're seeing something like `CODE(0xDEADBEEF)` when you print a subroutine reference because that's how Perl stringifies references. You see the say sort of thing if you print any sort of reference that doesn't overload stringification:

```
 $ perl -le 'print []'
 ARRAY(0x1008032b8)
```

Normally you can't really use that value for anything, and the number you see doesn't correspond necessarily to a real memory address.

For what you're doing, see the dynamic subroutine chapters I have in *Mastering Perl*. I talk quite a bit about the different things you can do to compose subroutines and work with anonymous subroutines. A module such as [Data::Constraint](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Data-Constraint) might even give you some ideas. I also talk about this in my answer to [How can a Perl force its caller to return?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2889215/8817).

Answer (score 1):

It might be possible (see [this similar problem and solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1671281/how-can-i-convert-the-stringified-version-of-array-reference-to-actual-array-refe)), but maybe there is another way. How about a (global?) hash that maps stringified code references to the actual code references?

```
my @fns = ();
for ( my $i = 0; $i < 10; $i++ ) {
  my $fn = eval "sub { print('I am function $i\n'); } ";
  if (ref $fn eq 'CODE') {
      $CODETABLE{$fn} = $fn;
  }
  push @fns, $fn;
}

...

my $evalcode = "sub {";
foreach ( @fns ) {
    # convert stringified code ref to the actual code ref
    $evalcode .= "\$CODETABLE{\"$_\"}->();";
}
$evalcode .= "}";

(eval $evalcode)->();
```

---

```
I am function 0
I am function 1
I am function 2
I am function 3
I am function 4
I am function 5
I am function 6
I am function 7
I am function 8
I am function 9
```

Comment: If lexical closures work, though, then that is the way to go.